# tensorflow equivalent of torch.gather

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I have a tensor of shape `(16, 4096, 3)`. I have another tensor of indices of shape `(16, 32768, 3)`. I am trying to collect the values along `dim=1`. This was initially done in pytorch using [gather function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather) as shown below-

```
# a.shape (16L, 4096L, 3L)
# idx.shape (16L, 32768L, 3L)
b = a.gather(1, idx)
# b.shape (16L, 32768L, 3L)
```

Please note that the size of output `b` is the same as that of `idx`. However, when I apply `gather` function of tensorflow, I get a completely different output. The output dimension was found mismatching as shown below-

```
b = tf.gather(a, idx, axis=1)
# b.shape (16, 16, 32768, 3, 3)
```

I also tried using `tf.gather_nd` but got in vain. See below-

```
b = tf.gather_nd(a, idx)
# b.shape (16, 32768)
```

Why am I getting different shapes of tensors? *I want to get the tensor of the same shape as calculated by pytorch.*

**In other words, I want to know the tensorflow equivalent of torch.gather.**

Comment: any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 3):

For 2D case,there is a method to do it:

```
# a.shape (16L, 10L)
# idx.shape (16L,1)
idx = tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(idx)[0]),idx[:,0]],axis=-1)
b = tf.gather_nd(a,idx)
```

However,For ND case,this method maybe very complex

Comment: Can you please try to incorporate for the example given above?

Answer (score 2):

This "should" be a general solution using tf.gather_nd (I've only tested for rank 2 and 3 tensors along the last axis):

```
def torch_gather(x, indices, gather_axis):
    # if pytorch gather indices are
    # [[[0, 10, 20], [0, 10, 20], [0, 10, 20]],
    #  [[0, 10, 20], [0, 10, 20], [0, 10, 20]]]
    # tf nd_gather needs to be
    # [[0,0,0], [0,0,10], [0,0,20], [0,1,0], [0,1,10], [0,1,20], [0,2,0], [0,2,10], [0,2,20],
    #  [1,0,0], [1,0,10], [1,0,20], [1,1,0], [1,1,10], [1,1,20], [1,2,0], [1,2,10], [1,2,20]]

    # create a tensor containing indices of each element
    all_indices = tf.where(tf.fill(indices.shape, True))
    gather_locations = tf.reshape(indices, [indices.shape.num_elements()])

    # splice in our pytorch style index at the correct axis
    gather_indices = []
    for axis in range(len(indices.shape)):
        if axis == gather_axis:
            gather_indices.append(gather_locations)
        else:
            gather_indices.append(all_indices[:, axis])

    gather_indices = tf.stack(gather_indices, axis=-1)
    gathered = tf.gather_nd(x, gather_indices)
    reshaped = tf.reshape(gathered, indices.shape)
    return reshaped
```

Answer (score 0):

For the last-axis gathering, we can use the 2D-reshape trick for general ND cases, and then employ @LiShaoyuan 2D code above

```
        # last-axis gathering only - use 2D-reshape-trick for Torch's style nD gathering
        def torch_gather(param, id_tensor):

            # 2d-gather torch equivalent from @LiShaoyuan above 
            def gather2d(target, id_tensor):
                idx = tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(id_tensor)[0]),id_tensor[:,0]],axis=-1)
                result = tf.gather_nd(target,idx)
                return tf.expand_dims(result,axis=-1)

            target = tf.reshape(param, (-1, param.shape[-1])) # reshape 2D
            target_shape = id_tensor.shape

            id_tensor = tf.reshape(id_tensor, (-1, 1)) # also 2D-index
            result = gather2d(target, id_tensor)
            return tf.reshape(result, target_shape)
```