# The tensorflow equivalent implementation of pytorch gather()

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

If I have a tensor ***S*** whose size is (2,1,64,512) and an index tensor ***D*** whose size is (2,5,64,512). In pytorch, I can extract values from S along axis=1 according to D by: `o = torch.gather(S, D, axis=1)`, which results in a new tensor of size (2,5,64,512).

I am wondering is there a way that can produce the same results using tensorflow even the tensor's size is different.

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure but, [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) would be similar to [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tensorflow equivalent of torch.gather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129909/tensorflow-equivalent-of-torch-gather)