# Tensorflow: Create the torch.gather() equivalent in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I want to replicate the `torch.gather()` function in TensorFlow 2.X.
I have a Tensor **A** (shape: `[2, 4, 3]`) and a corresponding Index-Tensor **I** (shape: `[2,2,3]`).
Using `torch.gather()` yields the following:

```
A = torch.tensor([[[10,20,30], [100,200,300], [1000,2000,3000]],
                  [[50,60,70], [500,600,700], [5000,6000,7000]]])
I = torch.tensor([[[0,1,0], [1,2,1]],
                  [[2,1,2], [1,0,1]]])
torch.gather(A, 1, I)

>
tensor([[[10,   200,   30], [100, 2000, 300]],
         [5000, 600, 7000], [500,   60, 700]]])
```

I have tried using `tf.gather()`, but this did not yield pytorch-like results. I also tried to play around with `tf.gather_nd()`, but I could not find a suitable solution.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129909/tensorflow-equivalent-of-torch-gather/52642327) StackOverflow post, but this seems not to work for me.

Edit:
When using `tf.gather_nd(A, I)`, I get the following result:

```
tf.gather_nd(A, I)

>
[[100, 6000],
 [  0,   60]]
```

The result for `tf.gather(A, I)` is rather lengthy. It has the shape of `[2, 2, 3, 4, 3]`

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example in tf?

Comment: @Ivan as requested, I added the examples for `tf.gather()` and `tf.gather_nd()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`torch.gather` and `tf.gather_nd` work differently and will therefore yield different results when using the same indices tensor (in some cases an error will also be returned). This is what the indices tensor would have to look like to get the same results:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.constant([[
                   [10,20,30], [100,200,300], [1000,2000,3000]],
                  [[50,60,70], [500,600,700], [5000,6000,7000]]])
I = tf.constant([[[
                  [0,0,0],
                  [0,1,1], 
                  [0,0,2],
                ],[
                  [0,1,0],
                  [0,2,1],
                  [0,1,2],  
                ]], 
                 [[
                  [1,2,0],
                  [1,1,1],
                  [1,2,2],  
                ], 
                  [
                  [1,1,0],
                  [1,0,1],
                  [1,1,2],  
                ]]])


print(tf.gather_nd(A, I))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[  10  200   30]
  [ 100 2000  300]]

 [[5000  600 7000]
  [ 500   60  700]]], shape=(2, 2, 3), dtype=int32)
```

So, the question is actually how are you calculating your indices or are they always hard-coded? Also, check out this [post](https://gundo0102.medium.com/comparison-of-torch-gather-and-tf-gather-nd-c306d05417b6) on the differences of the two operations.

As for the post you linked that didn't work for you, you just need to cast the indices and everything should be fine:

```py
def torch_gather(x, indices, gather_axis):

    all_indices = tf.where(tf.fill(indices.shape, True))
    gather_locations = tf.reshape(indices, [indices.shape.num_elements()])

    gather_indices = []
    for axis in range(len(indices.shape)):
        if axis == gather_axis:
            gather_indices.append(tf.cast(gather_locations, dtype=tf.int64))
        else:
            gather_indices.append(tf.cast(all_indices[:, axis], dtype=tf.int64))

    gather_indices = tf.stack(gather_indices, axis=-1)
    gathered = tf.gather_nd(x, gather_indices)
    reshaped = tf.reshape(gathered, indices.shape)
    return reshaped

I = tf.constant([[[0,1,0], [1,2,1]],
                  [[2,1,2], [1,0,1]]])
A = tf.constant([[
                   [10,20,30], [100,200,300], [1000,2000,3000]],
                  [[50,60,70], [500,600,700], [5000,6000,7000]]])
print(torch_gather(A, I, 1))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[  10  200   30]
  [ 100 2000  300]]

 [[5000  600 7000]
  [ 500   60  700]]], shape=(2, 2, 3), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel a little ashamed now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this as an equivalent to torch.gather:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import torch

# torch.gather equivalent
def tf_gather(x: tf.Tensor, indices: tf.Tensor, axis: int) -> tf.Tensor:
    complete_indices = np.array(np.where(indices > -1))
    complete_indices[axis] = tf.reshape(indices, [-1])
    flat_ind = np.ravel_multi_index(tuple(complete_indices), x.shape)
    return tf.reshape(tf.gather(tf.reshape(x, [-1]), flat_ind), indices.shape)


# ======= test program ========
if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = np.random.rand(2, 5, 3, 4)
    dim = 2  # 0 <= dim < len(a.shape))

    ind = np.expand_dims(np.argmax(a, axis=dim), axis=dim)

    # ========== np: groundtruth ==========
    np_max = np.expand_dims(np.max(a, axis=dim), axis=dim)

    # ========= torch: gather =========
    torch_max = torch.gather(torch.tensor(a), dim=dim, index=torch.tensor(ind))

    # ========= tensorflow: torch-like gather =========
    tf_max = tf_gather(tf.convert_to_tensor(a), axis=dim, indices=tf.convert_to_tensor(ind))

    keepdim = False
    if not keepdim:
        np_max = np.squeeze(np_max, axis=dim)
        torch_max = torch.squeeze(torch_max, dim=dim)
        tf_max = tf.squeeze(tf_max, axis=dim)

    # print('np_max:\n', np_max)
    # print('torch_max:\n', torch_max)
    # print('tf_max:\n', tf_max)

    assert np.allclose(np_max, torch_max.numpy()), '\33[1m\33[31mError with torch\33[0m'
    assert np.allclose(np_max, tf_max.numpy()), '\33[1m\33[31mError with tensorflow\33[0m'

    print('\33[1m\33[32mSuccess!\33[0m')
```